# Not all fonts are being applied with CSS3

Tags: css, font-face

I have a problem with fonts. I don't understand why this NeoSansStd-Italic works but the title "As melhores ..." doesn't apply the font NeoSansStd-BlackItalic.

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'NeoSansStd-BlackItalic';
    src: url('NeoSansStd-BlackItalic.otf');
    font-family:'NeoSansStd-Italic';
    src: url('NeoSansStd-Italic.otf');
    font-family: 'NeoSansStd-LightItalic';
    src: url('NeoSansStd-LightItalic.otf');
    }
```

works, but

```
#creditos {
  width:390px; 
  height:20px; 
  float:right;  
  margin-top:20px;
  color:#FFF;
font-size:13px;
font-family:'NeoSansStd-Italic'; 
font-style:italic;
    }
```

doesn't work

```
#titulo {
    width:600px;
    height:70px;
    font-family:'NeoSansStd-BlackItalic';
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    color:#FFF;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
    }
```

I don't have any idea why!

Comment: Don't you need 3 @font-face definitions since you have 3 different fonts??

Comment: what is the address of the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved

with

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'NeoSansStd-BoldItalic';
    src: url('NeoSansStd-BoldItalic.otf');
    }

@font-face {
    font-family: 'NeoSansStd-LightItalic';
    src: url('NeoSansStd-LightItalic.otf');
    }
```